# Largest range of consecutive integers that can be formed

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, logic, puzzle

Using a 10-element multiset of $\{1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100\}$, what's the largest range of consecutive integer values that can be produced (note that $0$ isn't counted)?

For example, I could take ten ones to get a range of $1$ to $10$, which would give me an answer of $10 - 1 = 9$. I can't seem to do any better than $9$. Can someone please help me with this problem? I don't think that ten ones is the answer because it seems too simple.

Comment: "Produced" in what way?  As sums of subsets?

Comment: I assume that "produced" means that you get to add the elements of the multiset?

Comment: Yes. You can choose any subset of your $10$-element multiset.

Comment: If that reading is correct, then taking $\{1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,5\}$ lets you produce every integer from $1$ to $34$, for example.  (to be clear, I expect that is very far from optimal).

Comment: $1,2,2,5,10,20,20,50,100,100$ is the best I've been able to do.

Comment: @saulspatz  Me too.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, that is optimal according to my program.  It gives all integers from $1$ to $310$.

Comment: Incidentally, these are the coin denominations in Hong Kong (and I imagine, other places), so saulspatz's answer is "intuitively obvious".  But is there a way to prove it is optimal without resorting to software search?

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101897/largest-range-of-consecutive-integers-that-can-be-formed